# auto metakey value on post tile

Tags: php, functions

I have this metakey "word_srch" the metakey has no value, i have to input the value in the custom field in the backed, instead, how can i create a function code that will automatically input the value base on the post title?

I read some materials but i think im missing some of it, add_post_meta but how can i call the post title in function.php code

update_post_meta($posid,'word_srch',$posttitle)
$posid=?
$posttitle=?

thankyou

Comment: `global $post; $post->ID; get_the_title( $post->ID );` ?

Comment: Is it possible to only use the metakey 'word_srch' and the value of the metakey will be based on the post title?

Comment: Yes you can use `word_srch` meta name because each post has its own ID in the table so nothing would go wrong, if I am getting you well

Comment: Hi, first of all i wanted to say thankyou I'm having improvements. one more questions i have this code below, how can i create a if else condition, if there is no value input, $ptitle is the value, but if there is a input value, it will get the value from the textbox: this is the code so far <?php 
      global $post; 
      $ptitle= get_the_title( $post->ID );
      update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'word_srch', $ptitle );
      ?>
      
      <input type="text"></input>

Comment: First off add a tag name to the input in the form like this `<input type="text" name="ptitle" />`. Now supposing you have control over form data, that field value can be accessed through `$_POST['ptitle']` if the form method is `post` so : `$ptitle = isset( $_POST['ptitle'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['ptitle'] ) : get_the_title( $post->ID );` hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I'll give it a shot, I'm noprofessional coder, but I'll find some more reading to understand the code you given :) thankyou very much Samuel for time to reply :) thankyou

Comment: No worries.. since comments here should be tiny, I put if else statement into 1 line: `$variable = condition ? if condition /*true*/ : else /*false*/;`. Same as `if( isset( $_POST['ptitle'] ) ) { $ptitle = $_POST['ptitle']; } else { $ptitle = get_the_title( $post->ID ); }`